# Get arraylist in restful jersy client

Tags: java, web-services, arraylist, jersey, jersey-client

I have the following service that return arraylist of object ,I have created restful client to return this arraylist but it return string like the following code,Now I want to retrieve it as arraylist of object .

Web service code that return arraylist of object

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/getQuery",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<User> get() throws JSONException {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

jersy client

```
Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client
               .resource("http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/getQuery");
            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                       .get(ClientResponse.class);

            String output =  response.getEntity(String.class);

            //how to get arraylist from responce
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, recommended is to send JSON or XML response from Server and manipulate it on Client side.

Try this,

Rest Service

```
 public Response saveDataIntoHash() {
        List<User> us= userRepository.findAll();

        GenericEntity generic = new GenericEntity<List<User>>(us){};
        return Response.status(201).entity(generic).build();
    }
```

Here is the client side

```
Client c = Client.create(config);

WebResource resource = c.resource(Main.BASE_URI);
ClientResponse response = resource.path("getQuery")
        .accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

List<User> users
            = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<User>>(){});

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("=== User===\n");
for (User u: users) {
    builder.append("Name: ").append(u.getName()).append("\n");          
}
builder.append("==================");
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this one.
My restservice is sending Arraylist list. I used this method for restclient to bring arraylist data from restservice

```
    public static void getAllData() {
        String uri = "http://localhost:8185/staff";
        try {
            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
            WebResource resource = client.resource(uri);
            ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
            if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
                ArrayList<Staff> list = response.getEntity(new GenericType<ArrayList<Staff>>() {});
                for (Staff staff : list) System.out.println(staff);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Exception is:" + e.getMessage()); }
    }
```

My entity is this.

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class Staff {
    private Long staffid;
        private String staffname;
        private String stafflastname;
        private String gender;
        private String email;
        private String city;

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }
        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }
        public Long getStaffid() {
            return staffid;
        }
        public void setStaffid(Long staffid) {
            this.staffid = staffid;
        }
        public String getStaffname() {
            return staffname;
        }
        public void setStaffname(String staffname) {
            this.staffname = staffname;
        }
        public String getStafflastname() {
            return stafflastname;
        }
        public void setStafflastname(String stafflastname) {
            this.stafflastname = stafflastname;
        }
        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }
        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Staff [staffid=" + staffid + ", staffname=" + staffname + ", stafflastname=" + stafflastname
                    + ", gender=" + gender + ", email=" + email + ", city=" + city + "]";
        }

    }
```